# React doesn't update state from several sources after a click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I created a shopping list. Each item in the list has 2 options: "Remove" (will remove the specific item from the shopping list), and "Edit" (let the user changing the size or/and the quantity of the specific item). My problem is when I'm trying to edit the items by changing the size, quantity, and removing some of them, everything works but after several items that I'm changing/removing, the quantity and the sizing lists aren't updating in the right way. I have been trying so many different approaches but couldn't find out what is the root of the problem.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Components/header';
import Item from './Components/item';
import ItemProperties from './Components/itemProperties';
import { shirtsList } from './shirtsList';
import CustomerHelp from './Components/customerHelp';
import Checkout from './Components/checkout';
import EditPage from './Components/editPage';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quantity: {},
      totalItems: 0,
      sizing: {},
      editItem: [],
      cart: shirtsList
    }
  }


// Item component

  handleRemoveItem(shirt) {
    const newCart = this.state.cart.filter((item) => {
      return shirt.id !== item.id
    })
    this.setState({cart: newCart})
    //--------------------------------------------------------//
    const newQuantity = this.state.quantity.filter((item) => {
      return shirt.id !== item.id
    })
    this.setState({quantity: newQuantity})
    //--------------------------------------------------------//
    const newSizing = this.state.sizing.filter((item) => {
      return shirt.id !== item.id
    })
    this.setState({sizing: newSizing})
    //--------------------------------------------------------//
    let totall = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < newQuantity.length; i++){
      totall = totall + newQuantity[i].amount;
    }
    this.setState({totalItems: totall})
  }

  openItemEvent(shirt) {
    const itemToEdit = this.state.cart.filter((item) => {
      return shirt.id === item.id
    })
    this.setState({editItem: itemToEdit})
    document.querySelector('.mainEditPage').style.display = 'flex';

}


// Checkout component
  subTotalPrice = () => {
    let total = 0;
    let quantity = this.state.quantity;
    let cart = this.state.cart;
    for(let i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++){
      if(cart[i].price === cart[i].oldPrice && cart.length > 0){
        total = total + quantity[i].amount * cart[i].price;
      } else{
        total = total + quantity[i].amount * cart[i].price;
      }
    }
    return total.toFixed(2);
  }


// EditPage component

  changingSize = (event, shirt) =>{
    let currentSize = event.target.value;
    this.newSizes = this.state.sizing.map((i, num) => {
      if(i.id === shirt.id){
        return {size: currentSize,id: num+1}
      }else {
        return {size: i.size ,id: num+1}
      }
    })
  }

  changingQuantity = (event, shirt) =>{
    let currentQuantity = event.target.value;
    this.newQuantity = this.state.quantity.map((i, num) => {
      if(i.id === shirt.id){
        return {amount: Number(currentQuantity), id: num+1}
      }else {
        return {amount: Number(i.amount) ,id: num+1}
      }
    })
  }

  editButton = () =>{
    let total = 0;

    // Setting up "sizing" state after pressing the edit button
    if(this.newSizes === undefined) {
      this.setState({sizing: this.state.cart.map((shirt, i) => {
        return {size: shirt.size,id: i+1}
      })})
    }else {
      this.setState({sizing: this.newSizes})
    }

    // Setting up "quantity" and "totalItems" state after pressing the edit button
    if(this.newQuantity === undefined) {
      this.setState({quantity: this.state.cart.map((shirt, i) => {
        return {amount: shirt.quantity,id: i+1}   
      })})

      for(let i = 0; i < this.state.quantity.length; i++){
        total = total + this.state.quantity[i].amount;
      }
      this.setState({totalItems: total})

    }else {
      this.setState({quantity: this.newQuantity})  

      for(let i = 0; i < this.newQuantity.length; i++){
        total = total + this.newQuantity[i].amount;
      }
      this.setState({totalItems: total})
    }

    document.querySelector('.mainEditPage').style.display = 'none';

  }

  exitButton() {
    document.querySelector('.mainEditPage').style.display = 'none';
  }


// React lifeCycle methods

componentWillMount(){
  this.getQuantity();
  this.getSize();
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.getTotalItems();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------//


  getSize = () =>{
    const array = shirtsList.map((shirt, i) => {
      return {size: shirt.size,id: i+1}
    })
    this.setState({sizing: array})
  }


  getQuantity = () =>{
    const array = shirtsList.map((shirt, i) => {
      return {amount: shirt.quantity,id: i+1}
    })
    this.setState({quantity: array})
  }

  getTotalItems = () =>{
    let total = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.quantity.length; i++){
      total = total + this.state.quantity[i].amount;
    }
    this.setState({totalItems: total})

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <ItemProperties amount={this.state.totalItems}/>
        <div className="itemInTheCart">

        {
          this.state.cart.map((shirt, i) => {
          return ( 
            <Item 
              name={shirt.name} 
              price={shirt.price} 
              oldPrice={shirt.oldPrice} 
              color={shirt.color} 
              style1={shirt.style} 
              image={shirt.image}
              quantity={this.state.quantity[i].amount}
              size={this.state.sizing[i].size}
              key={shirt.id}
              handleRemoveItem={() => {this.handleRemoveItem(shirt)}}
              openItemEvent={() => {this.openItemEvent(shirt)}}
            />
            ) 
          })
        }
        </div>
        <div className="checkout__section">
          <CustomerHelp />
          <Checkout 
            change={this.subTotalPrice()}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mainEditPage">  

          {
            this.state.editItem.map((shirt) => {
              return ( 
                <EditPage
                  image={shirt.image}
                  name={shirt.name}
                  price={shirt.price}
                  style={shirt.style}
                  color={shirt.color}
                  key={shirt.id}
                  size={shirt.size}
                  exitButton={() => {this.exitButton()}}
                  changingSize={(event) =>{this.changingSize(event, shirt)}}
                  changingQuantity={(event) =>{this.changingQuantity(event, shirt)}}
                  editButton={() => {this.editButton()}}
                />
              )  
            })
          }

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `sizing lists aren't updating in the right way` what do you mean by this? is it getting slower? is it not updating at all?

Comment: After editing some items and then removing some, the lists aren't updating with the right items inside them. In the main cart list, for example there items number 1 and 4 are left, and in the two other lists (sizing and quantity) items 1 and 2 are left.

Comment: call setState only one time like this.setState({ .cart : newCart, quantity : newQuantity,  totalItems: totall, sizing: newSizing }) at last line of handleRemoveItem

Comment: It is still doesn't work properly. It gives me the error:
Cannot read property 'price' of undefined Line: 66. Basically it is line 6 in  "SubTotalPrice". It is working for several times and then I'm trying to remove another item and it gives me an error again

Comment: so `setState` does lazy updates. In the code there are several calls to it which is OK because it also batches updates. However if you update a property X and then immediately in the next line try to do something with another property Y which depends on X, the code will not work as intended because X will still have the old value. `setState` changes occur *after* the function which is calling it exits. Try rewriting the updates with this in mind.